# How to add an exception to "CSS Top, JavaScript Bottom" Wordpress Function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function

How can I add an exception to this wordpress function code, I have javascripts need to be where they are so the image slider can work correctly.

example: files I want exclude from this function; slider1.js slider2.js slider1.css slider2.css

```
//Automatically move JavaScript code to page footer, speeding up page loading time.
function footer_enqueue_scripts() {
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_scripts');
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 9);
remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 1);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_print_head_scripts', 5);
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'footer_enqueue_scripts');
```

Comment: this is run in the php side (server side) not client side, so you CANT performance a try catch there, you should create the try and catch in the client side, javascript

Comment: @ncubica he doesn't mean a programmatic exception, he means "an exception to the rule".

Answer (score 0):

You can dequeue a script:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script

```
 <?php wp_dequeue_script( $handle ); ?>
```

This will remove it from the scripts you're adding with `wp_enqueue_scripts`. You need to know the name (handle) it was enqueued with.

For example, if it was enqueued like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my_slider_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'slider1.js' );
```

You would dequeue like this:

```
//CALL DEQUEUE BEFORE YOU CALL add_action('wp_footer', 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 5);
wp_dequeue_script( 'my_slider_script' );
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It didn't work. The files I want to exclude are: jquery-core.js and jquery.timers.js If you can implment them within the code I posted that would be great as I can't make sense of what I have done is right or wrong because the page went messy. Thanks anyway